# What to do about GitHub warning about jquery in my bookdown output

Tags: github, bookdown

GitHub is complaining about a security issue in one of my r `bookdown` based projects.

https://github.com/RaymondBalise/Agresti_IntroToCategorical/security/dependabot/2

The warning is pointing to a path to a library that I don't think I am using.   I updated the project a couple months ago and I only see jquery-3.6.0 in the repo.

I am reluctant to just dismiss it because I am mostly clueless.   Can someone with a clue tell me how to check to see if this is a real problem or a false alarm?